# selec2 dropdown not working while running web-application in IIS(windows 7)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, jquery-select2

Im completed my asp.net web-application by using VisulaStudio2013 in which all controls are working fine. After that i copied published files in IIS-7 pc(OS:Windows 7) then select2 dropdown not loading its data's properly. 
please chek my codes given below:-

---

```
 searchType = "Name";
 $("#CustomerId").select2({

    placeholder: 'Search options',
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    ajax: {
        url: "/ProductEnquiry/GetCustomerMobileNumbers",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function (term, page, type) {
            return {
                q: term, //search term
                page: page, // page number
                type: searchType
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            alert(data);
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            var more = (page * 30) < data.total_count; // whether or not there are more results available
            return { results: data.items, more: more };
        }
    }
  });
```

In that alert box shows 'null' values..

```
public JsonResult GetCustomerMobileNumbers(string q, int page, string type)
{
    try
    {
        HttpCookie _UserInfoCookies = Request.Cookies["UserInfo"];
        string UserId = _UserInfoCookies["UserId"];
        string BranchId = _UserInfoCookies["BranchId"];
        var branchDetails = branchService.GetBranchDetailsByBranchId(Convert.ToInt32(BranchId));
        var list = customerService.GetAllCustomerMobileNumbersBySearch(q, 30 * (page - 1), 30, Convert.ToInt32(branchDetails.CompanyId), type);
        SelectDropDownViewModel dummy = new SelectDropDownViewModel()
        {
            id = 0,
            text = "no data found",
        };
        IEnumerable<SelectDropDownViewModel> Data = new List<SelectDropDownViewModel>();
        if (type == "Name")
        {
            Data = list.Select(c => new SelectDropDownViewModel { id = c.CustomerId, text = c.CustomerName }).AsEnumerable();
        }
        else if (type == "Mobile")
        {
            Data = list.Select(c => new SelectDropDownViewModel { id = c.CustomerId, text = c.Mobile }).AsEnumerable();
        }
        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = true, results = Data, items = Data, total_count = Data.Count() }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogs errorLog = new ErrorLogs() { Source = "ProductEnquiry", Message = ex.Message, InnerException = Convert.ToString(ex.InnerException), HelpLink = ex.HelpLink, TimeOccured = DateTime.UtcNow, StackTrace = ex.StackTrace };
        errorLogService.AddItem(errorLog);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Im already installed .net frame work 4.0 & 4.5 in that pc for running IIS-local host.
Please help me resolve this issue;

Comment: Why are you serializing you object twice - using `Json` and `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` and then undoing it in the view using `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: @Stephen brother,this   'data = JSON.parse(data);' for parsing json object and retreive data's. But it works fine in developer pc & IIS7 (in windows 10).... But the issue happening in IIS-local host in windows7 pc....

Comment: My comment was just in relation to the pointless exercise of serializing it twice and the having to undo one in the view :)

Comment: @Stephen brother; Ok ya that's u r right :-)
Can u suggest any solving method in my issue... in IIS didn't loading selec2 dropDown.....

Comment: Not familiar enough with `Select2` (but will have a look later if it remains unanswered). I would however recommend you use your browser tools to check for any errors in the console. And change you url to use `url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomerMobileNumbers", "ProductEnquiry")',` so its always correctly generated.